# How to wrap a sentence with a certain word in Jquery

Tags: jquery, contains

How do I do this one in jquery? Say I have

```
<div class = "container">
      The requested quantity for "ITEM" is not available

      <span>Other word</span>
</div>
```

if the container has this phrase "The requested quantity for" 
then wrap the entire sentence in

```
<h1></h1>
```

this will be the output:

```
<div class = "container">
      <h1>The requested quantity for "ITEM" is not available</h1>

      <span>Other word</span>
</div>
```

THANKS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:-

```
$('.container').html('<h2>'+$('.container').text()+'</h2>');
```

or you can also use [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/):-

```
$('.container').wrapInner('<h2/>');
```

**Answer for updated question**:-

```
$('.container').contents()
    .filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3})
    .wrap('<h2 />');
```

[Demo for wrapInner](https://jsfiddle.net/guzzjty1/23/)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guzzjty1/22/)

Comment: how can I do that if my markup is like this

<div class = "container">
      The requested quantity for "ITEM" is not available

       <span>Sample</span>
</div>

and I want only the first sentence that has "The requested quantity for" to be affected?

so the output is <h1>The requested quantity for "ITEM" is not available</h1> <span>Sample</span>

thanks

Comment: @KenAvila i am using same markup in demo check the demo

Comment: what if I have other elements inside the container but I want only the first sentence that I gave to be affected?

Comment: @KenAvila can you provide that markup so i can help thanks

Comment: <div class = "container">
      The requested quantity for "ITEM" is not available                        <span>Other word</span>
</div>

I just want to wrap the first sentence which is "The requested quantity for "ITEM" is not available "

Comment: so the result will be <h1>The requested quantity for "ITEM" is not available </h1> <span>Other word</span>

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#container").html('<h1>'+$("#container").html()+'</h1>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.container').each(function(index){
    if($(this).html().indexOf("The requested quantity for") > -1)
    {
        $(this).html("<h1>" + $(this).html() + "</h1>");
    }
});
```